# Additional authorizing in Google App script to run google chat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, chatbot

I've created chat bot, and it's work, but after adding my bot to chat i had to configure and authorization it. It's clear, but i had to run script  as well manually to get more authorization, without it i don't have access to my bot's functionality. How can I resolve that problem, so that another users of this chat didn't have to run script manually to get access to use chat bot ?

Comment: Are you using a paid Google Workspace account or using a Gmail.com account?

Comment: paid Google Workspace account

Answer (score 1):

I made a chatbot as a test, and it's working without running the Apps Script. Here are the steps that I followed (You can review them and see if one of those helps you):

1. Create the Chatbot, run it once manually to allow the permissions, and deploy it as an add-on. Save the deployment ID somewhere since you will use it in step 9.

[image]

[image]

2. Create a [new project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project) inside the Google Cloud console.
3. Copy the Google Cloud project number, and save it somewhere since you will use it in step 5.
4. Set a [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent). *(Mainly because you will get an error when you try to add the project without it. If you like you can add the scopes of chat but is not a requirement)*

[image]

5. Set the `Apps Script project's Google Cloud project`.

[image]

[image]

6. Enable the [Chat API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/enable-apis).

[image]

[image]

7. Click `configuration`, after adding the Chat API.

[image]

8. Add all the required information there, including the Apps Script project deployment ID; and if the chatbot will be available for the entire domain or just a group of people.
9. Save the changes. After that, I subscribed to both with another account without issues and without being requested to run the bot.

[image]

**Reference**

- [Google Apps Script Chat app](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/apps-script-app)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help. I' ve just figured out where the problem was. To be more specific the problem was in my cod (of course) in   onCardClick(event) function. I used  "Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())". This made the bot unresponsive

Comment: I glad to hear that s working. Thank you for letting me know.